# how to resolve it

Tags: sql

i'm to study sql and don't got resolved this, anybody could help me?

1. Display person of runners which are not winners;
2. Delete all runners which are not winners;

---

```
sql> SELECT * FROM runners;
+----+---------------+
| id | person        |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Mary Jane     |
| 2  | Louis Luck    |
| 3  | Will Kirk     |
| 4  | Torny Marks   |
| 5  | Denn Clarks   |
+----+---------------+

sql> SELECT * FROM races;
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id | race             | id_winner |
+----+------------------+-----------+
| 1  | race-stick       | 2         |
| 2  | 400 meter        | 3         |
| 3  | atletic march    | 2         |
| 4  | 50 meter         | 4         |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

thanks!!!

Comment: What queries have you tried so far in your attempt to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

NOT IN example

```
1. SELECT * FROM runners WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_winner FROM races);

2. DELETE FROM runners WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_winner FROM races);
```

NOT EXISTS example

```
1. SELECT * FROM runners a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM races WHERE id_winner = a.id);

2. DELETE a FROM runners a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM races WHERE id_winner = a.id);
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous, when it comes to null values. Do NOT EXISTS instead.

Comment: Yup, his requirement is simple. For bigger datasets, NOT EXISTS is better.

Comment: The warning is about null values, not the sizes of data sets. (Besides, most dbms products optimize the same way today.)